# Web crawler storing visited urls in file

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, web-crawler

I'm having issues with figuring out how I can store and scan large amounts of visited URLS from a web crawler. The idea is that the number of visited URL's will eventually be too much to store in memory and I should store them in file but I was wondering, doesn't this become very inefficient? If after getting a batch of URL's and I want to check if the URL is already visited I have to check the visited file line by line and see if there is a match?

I had thought about using a cache but the problem still remains when the URL is not found in the cache and I would still have to check the file. Do I have to check the file line-by-line for every URL and is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key data-structure here could be a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), and [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) provides an implementation. The Bloom-filter would tell you (maybe you have visited the URL) or you haven't surely. If the result is a maybe you can go and check the file if it's already visited otherwise you go and visit the URL and store it in the file as well as in the Bloom Filter.
Now, to optimise the file seeks, you can hash the URL to get a fixed size `byte[]` rather than unfixed string length (ex: md5).

```
byte[] hash = md5(url);
if(bloomFilter.maybe(hash)){
  checkTheFile(hash);
}else{
 visitUrl(url);
 addToFile(hash);
 addToBloomFilter(hash);
}
```

You can use a database and the hash being the primary key to get a `O(1)` access time when you check if a key exists, or You can implement an [index](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter11/node1.html) yourself.

Comment: If I have to check the file is scanning the file line by line for the matching url (or in your suggestion stored hashes) my best option? Or could I maybe save a serialized data structure e.g map and check that way?

Comment: storing hashes will optimise the file seeks, incase of md5 you increase the offset with 128 bits every time to get to the next hash, so you end up with a small file size and buffering becomes easier

Answer (score 0):

What about having a file per URL? If the file exists then the URL has been crawled.

You can then get more sophisticated and have this file contain data that indicates the results of the last crawl, how long you want to wait before the next crawl, etc. (It's handy to be able to spot 404s, for example, and decide whether to try again or abandon that URL.)

With this approach, it's worth normalising the URLs so that minor differences in the URL don't result in different files.

I've used this technique in my node crawler (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-nutch) and it allows me to store the status either in the file system (for simple crawls) or on S3 (for crawls involving more than one server).